# Store an XML into a HashMap

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I need to store the XML's text nodes in a HashMap such that the key is the tagname and the value is the Tag's content.

I'm able to do this partially using the below code. However the problem is that even though I am able to get the text nodes but I'm also getting the other (or redundant) tags as well. I just need to get the data from the SimpleElements(no child elements) in an XML, and Ignore the complexElements (that contains more XML tags inside them).

I'm unable to do this since whenever I try to fetch the node type, all the nodes returns the same type for some reason.

*P.S. I'm still learning to code, so be generous :)*

```
public class TextNodes {

    private static HashMap<String, String> printNote(NodeList a) {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.getLength(); i++) {
            Node x = a.item(i);

            if (x.hasChildNodes() == true) {
                int y = 1;
                String key = x.getNodeName();
                String tempkey = "";
                if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                    do {
                        y++;
                        tempkey = key + "_" + y;
                    } while (map.containsKey(tempkey) == true);
                    map.put(tempkey, x.getTextContent().trim());
                    tempkey = "";
                } else {
                    map.put(key, x.getTextContent().trim());
                }
            }
        }

        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File input = new File("test1.txt");
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(input);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            Element ele = doc.getDocumentElement();
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            if (doc.hasChildNodes()) {
                map = printNote(ele.getElementsByTagName("*"));

            }

            System.out.println(map.keySet());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want duplicates you could add the node to the map only when you get to the node value. This will ignore the child elements until they themselves present with their values.

```
  Node child = list.item(i);
        if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
            textContent.append(child.getTextContent());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, this doesn't solve the problem here.. I don't have any null nodes as such... So, I get the same output :(

Comment: what about checking to see if it is a text child, and only then adding the parent to the hash map? (see example)

Comment: What's the list we are using here?
But when I do this and feed it to the printNode() method, I get all the node types as ELEMENT_TYPE & all of them do have children, while thats not true...
>ele.getElementsByTagName("*")

Comment: Check the type all the children, and add the parent to the HashMap only when `(child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)`

Comment: It comes out to be false for each and every node for some reason... All the child nodes, parent nodes have ELEMENT_NODE as their NodeType

Comment: Any help here please!!